# Replace All references to email Pentaho Jobs error checking in Repository

Tags: javascript, xml, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have over 100 jobs (kjb) that reference an email address that is no longer active.
I wish to globally change the email address dynamically using PDI (spoon) in all jobs.

The jobs are in XML and are in a Pentaho Repository (Windows Server).

the code I wish to change in all jobs is:

```
  <destination>bubba</destination>
  <destinationCc/>
  <destinationBCc/>
  <replyto>bubba@there.com</replyto>
  <replytoname>Bubba</replytoname>
```

To:

```
  <destination>${EMAIL_ERROR_LIST}</destination>
  <destinationCc/>
  <destinationBCc/>
  <replyto>admin@here.com</replyto>
  <replytoname>admin</replytoname>
```

do we really need to make changes and then individually promote everything back to production, or could we somehow do this with a transformation dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

this is not a solution in PDI, but you can open all XML files (jobs) with text editor and searh the field you want to change by the other value.

The same thing in a repository, but you can searh in table for the specific jobs.

Comment: Since this is not a solution maybe you should've added it as comment.

Comment: I can't 'cause my reputation score @BernardoMarques,